# Iterating through 2 dimensional lists in 1 line

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, multidimensional-array

For a 2D list [["bacon", "banana"], ["ham", "salami", "cheese"]] I want to iterate through as "bacon", then "banana", then "ham" etc.

```
sandwiches = [["bacon", "banana"], ["ham", "salami", "cheese"]]
preferences = ["bacon", 5, "ham", -2, "salami", 1]
```

In the sandwiches array, there are 2 sandwiches, bacon+banana and ham+salami+cheese. I want to know the score for each sandwich by doing something like this (doesn't work but shows what I'd like to do):

```
sandwichscores = [0 for i in sandwiches]
sandwichscores = [+preferences[preferences.index(j)+1] for j in i in sandwiches if
j in preferences]
```

But of course for j in i in sandwiches doesn't work. I've tried messing around with the order of the fors and ins but haven't gotten anywhere. How could this be done?

For instance, the output I want here would be:

```
sandwichscores = [5, -1]
```

Since the ingredients have a combined score of 5 in the first sandwich and -1 in the second. The ingredients that aren't in the preferences get ignored.

Comment: You would be better off with a dictionary for your preferences: `preferences = { 'bacon' : 5, 'ham' : -2 }`

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  What comes after "bacon" and "banana" in the iteration?  Is it "ham" "salami" "cheese" or something else?  It's also unclear what output you want.

Comment: The order doesn't matter as long as each element iterates once.

Comment: Actually it does matter sorry, I've hopefully cleared up the ambiguity of the order I want.

Comment: don't you also want to know what each combination scored?

Comment: To be clear, do you want to generate the scores for bacon/ham, bacon/salami, bacon/cheese, banana/ham, banana/salami, banana/cheese?

Comment: In the sandwiches array, there are 2 sandwiches. The first sandwich is bacon+banana and the second is ham+salami+cheese. I want to know the score for each sandwich.

Comment: The filling gets ignored, which is why I have the if statement in the way I want to generate the sandwichscores list.

Comment: What's the score of cheese and banana?

Comment: Ingredients not in the preferences list get ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the logic you want to use, unpacked into a nested for loop:

```
for i, sandwich in enumerate(sandwiches):
    for filling in sandwich:
        if filling in preferences:
            sandwichscores[i] += preferences[preferences.index(filling)+1]
```

```
print(sandwichscores)
>>> [5, -1]
```

As i alarmed alien says, the logic is much simpler if you use a dictionary for the scores:

```
preferences = {'bacon':5,'ham':-2,'salami':1}

#...

for i, sandwich in enumerate(sandwiches):
    for filling in sandwich:
        sandwichscores[i] += preferences.get(filling, 0)
```

Comment: I enjoy making it short.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner that does what you want; I converted your preferences list into [a dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) because that is a [much more suitable data structure when you are storing key/value pairs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

```
sandwiches = [["bacon", "banana"], ["ham", "salami", "cheese"]]
prefs = {"bacon": 5, "ham": -2, "salami": 1}

scores = [ [ ", ".join(i), sum( prefs[j] for j in i if j in prefs) ] for i in sandwiches ]
print(scores)
```

Output:

```
[['bacon, banana', 5], ['ham, salami, cheese', -1]]
```

The solution uses [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to add up the values of the sandwich ingredients, which are filtered by whether or not the ingredient appears in `prefs`.

You can change the output format to remove the list of ingredients and just output the score by altering the `[ ", ".join(i), sum( prefs[j] for j in i if j in prefs) ]` part. I would have assumed it was important to know which sandwich got which score, but who knows!

Comment: `dict.get(key, 0)` is shorter then `prefs[j] for ... if j in prefs`

Comment: its what I used ;)

Comment: @PatrickArtner I hope the OP will take inspiration from both of our answers and investigate the amazing power of dictionaries further. ;D

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way in which you can do it, although I changed the structure of `preferences` to dictionary, which is more practical and easier to utilize:

```
sandwiches = [["bacon", "banana"], ["ham", "salami", "cheese"]]
preferences = {"bacon" : 5, "ham" : -2, "salami" : 1}

scores = [sum(preferences.get(ingredient,0) for ingredient in sandwich) for sandwich in sandwiches]
print(scores)
```

Output:

```
[5, -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one liner using `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

sandwiches = [["bacon", "banana"], ["ham", "salami", "cheese"]]
preferences = ["salami", 999, "bacon", 5, "ham", -2, "banana", 1000]

l = [(v, sum(i[-1] for i in g)) for v, g in groupby(((sandwich, preferences[preferences.index(p)+1]) for sandwich, prefs in zip(sandwiches, [preferences[::2]] * len(sandwiches)) for p in prefs if p in sandwich), key=lambda v: v[0])]
print(l)
```

Prints:

```
[(['bacon', 'banana'], 1005), (['ham', 'salami', 'cheese'], 997)]
```

For sandwich `['bacon', 'banana']`: Bacon has 5, banana has 1000, sandwich score is 1005

For sandwich `['ham', 'salami', 'cheese']`: Ham has -2, salami has 999, sanwich score is 997

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for the score lookup - it is the designated datastructure for lookups.

You can go from your representation of `preferences` to a dictionary with a dict-comprehension:

```
preferences = ["bacon", 5, "ham", -2, "salami", 1]

prefs = {k:v for k,v in zip(preferences[::2],preferences[1::2])} # dict-comprehension
```

This uses [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to join every 2nd element starting at 0 `["bacon","ham","salami"]` to every 2nd element starting at 1 `[5,-2,1]` resulting in a zip-generator of `(("bacon,5),("ham",-2),("salami",1))`.

The zip-generator-result is then decomposed into `key:value` pairs that create the dict.

---

With that out of the way, you can calculate your sums like so:

```
sandwiches = [["bacon", "banana"], ["ham", "salami", "cheese"]]
prefs = {"bacon": 5, "ham": -2, "salami": 1}

score = [ (sandw, sum( prefs.get(ingred,0) 
                       for ingred in sandw)) 
          for sandw in sandwiches ]

print(score)
```

The `score` sums up each ingredients score for each sandwinch you defined. If an ingredient is not found, 0 is added instead.

The output is a tuple of the sandwich and its score:

```
 [(['bacon', 'banana'], 5), (['ham', 'salami', 'cheese'], -1)]
```

Comment: How would you generate a dictionary from a text file? I've currently got:

Comment: preferences = [line.translate({ord(c): "" for c in " "}).translate({ord(c): " " for c in ","}).split() for line in file1] (gets rid of the spaces and commas and makes a 2d list of the preferences) and then preferences = sum(preferences, []) (turns the 2d array into a 1d one)